# A page can have only one server side form

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this error where a page has two forms but with different ID, i tried removing runat="server" as the form was not using User controls, the page loads with the forms but there button events/form validation doesn't work, please help if anyone have a better solution to this

[Ss from the page when it has two forms with different form ID's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXmGq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of web forms, yes, that is correct, you can ONLY have one server side form tag in that page.

However, WHY do you need more then one form tag?

In the VAST majority of cases, a simple div section for some particular content is fine, and there is no real issue or gain to having more then one form tag.

I suspect the issue here is miss-use of form tag, or that you think it has some function other then what defines the content for that given page. (it really has no other purpose here - and thus you should not care, mess with, or even give this issue any brain power here - it simple that each and every page will have a form tag.

If this is a master + child page setup, then it turns out the master page has the form tag for you already, and thus you ONLY placing content inside of the content area, say like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %></h2>
    <p>Your contact page.</p>

    <address>
        One Microsoft Way<br />
        Redmond, WA 98052-6399<br />
        <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr>
        425.555.0100
    </address>

    <address>
        <strong>Support:</strong><a href="mailto:Support@example.com">Support@example.com</a><br />
        <strong>Marketing:</strong><a href="mailto:Marketing@example.com">Marketing@example.com</a>
    </address>
</asp:Content>
```

So for any web page that has a master page, then you do NOT use or have nor place a form tag in that page.

However, for any page that is not part of a master/child page, then of course you only need and will have one form tag, and there is no valid reason or advantage to having or even wanting more then one form tag on a given page anyway.

I suspect your goal and question is not really related to a form tag, but for aspx web form pages, you only need one form tag, and in fact can only have one form tag.

Do feel free to add in comments to this post what you "real" goal here is, I can probably suggest some ideas to help you in your final goal that you looking to achieve here.

Comment: We need two forms as there are two forms which could be submitted via user , but since both the forms have different ID's they could be treated as different forms right?

Comment: It would not make any difference, since a post back is a post back is a post back. Any click of a submit button will post the whole page - so, no, it would never make a difference anyway.  If you need to separate out parts of the page, then a simple div will suffice. But, any button any place on the page would submit the whole web page, and thus the concept of the page form really does not matter, since a submit posts the whole page anyway.  And in code behind, when do you ever use the form id? (answer: never, and it never matters). If you want a partial page post back then use update panel